# Constrain horizontal centers between views not working

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I have two views on the screen of the same size. I constrain one view to sit exactly on top of the other view but it is not working.

I can look at my constraints on the interface builder and the line showing the x position matches up:

You can see the line for the constraint when I select frontview center:
[image]

And then as you see in the picture when I pick backview.centreX = frontview.centre.X the constraint line shows in the same place:

[image]

So as far as I can see the backview center x position should be constrained to be the same as the frontview center X position.

However the backview X ends up in a totally different position (see the logs where I print the strings of the CGFloat position for each):

```
BackView X Position is = 642.0
BackView Y Position is = 270.0
FrontView X Position is = 220.0
frontView Y Position is = 270.0
```

I thought maybe it was my code in printing out but that is fine (see below):

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
backViewXStartPosition = backview.center.x
backViewYStartPosition = backview.center.y

frontViewXStartPosition = frontview.center.x
frontViewYStartPosition = frontview.center.y

backViewXStartPositionString = String (backViewXStartPosition)
backViewYStartPositionString = String (backViewYStartPosition)
frontViewXStartPositionString = String (frontViewXStartPosition)
frontViewYStartPositionString = String (frontViewYStartPosition)

print ("BackView X Position is = "+backViewXStartPositionString )
print ("BackView Y Position is = "+backViewYStartPositionString )
print ("FrontView X Position is = "+frontViewXStartPositionString )
print ("frontView Y Position is = "+frontViewYStartPositionString )
```

I also check the other constraints on the backview thinking that they may override but I can't find anything there either. Is it normal for a cleary constrained horizontal center not to work?

Thanks for your help

Comment: print all your frame value in `viewDidAppear()` or in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and check

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Thanks. Tried in view did appear and same thing.

Answer (score 0):

check your backview's leading or trailing constraints if exist might be they are conflicting

Comment: Thanks, No trailing margins used for either of the views.

Comment: can you share your storyboard file?

Comment: Thanks, I cant now. I will do it in code for the time being. Tanks for taking the time though.